# client server with multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

i write a program client-server with multi threading for send - receive file.  The program runs and client send and server receive. the files are created but empty new files are created
Why?  please help me

class client :

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.net.Socket;


 public class Client extends Thread {

Socket socket = null;
Socket socket1 = null;
  public  void sendFile() throws IOException {

String host = "127.0.0.1";
String host1 = "127.0.0.2";

socket = new Socket(host, 1024);
socket1 = new Socket(host1, 1025);

File file = new File("/home/reza/Desktop/link help");
File file1 = new File("/home/reza/Desktop/hi");
long length = file.length();
long length1 = file1.length();
final byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];
final byte[] bytes1 = new byte[(int) length1];

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(file1);

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
final BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
final BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
final BufferedInputStream bis1 = new BufferedInputStream(fis1);
final BufferedOutputStream out1 = new BufferedOutputStream(socket1.getOutputStream());


 Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {



  public void run()
{


 while(socket.isConnected())
  {

 Wait2();


   try {
    System.out.println("ok");
    int count;

    while ((count = bis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
        out.write(bytes, 0, count);

   }
 } catch (IOException e) {

e.printStackTrace();
 }

  }
  }
  });

  Thread t1 = new Thread(new  Runnable() {
   public void run() {
 while(socket1.isConnected())
    {

     Wait2();

       try {
            System.out.println("ok1");
            int count1;
            while ((count1 = bis1.read(bytes1)) > 0) {
                out1.write(bytes1, 0, count1);

           }


    } catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

 }
 });
 t1.start();
 t.start();




socket.close();
socket1.close();
 }

 public void Wait2()

{


 try {

 Thread.sleep(3000);

 } catch (InterruptedException x) {

 System.out.println("Interrupted!");

 }

 }
 }
```

class server:

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.net.*;
public class Server  {

public Server()
{
 Thread t = new Thread(new Client());
 t.start();
 Thread t1 = new Thread(new Client());
 t1.start();    
 }



  //@SuppressWarnings("null")
  public  void recivefile() throws IOException {
   ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
 ServerSocket serverSocket1 = null;


try {

   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1024);


 } catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Can't setup server on this port number. ");
 }
 try {
     serverSocket1 = new ServerSocket(1025);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Can't setup server on this port number1. ");
    }


Socket socket = null;
Socket socket1 = null;

InputStream is = null;
InputStream is1 = null;

FileOutputStream fos = null;
FileOutputStream fos1 = null;

BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
BufferedOutputStream bos1 = null;

int bufferSize = 0;
int bufferSize1 = 0;


try {
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
   socket1 = serverSocket1.accept();




} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Can't accept client connection. ");
}

try {
    is = socket.getInputStream();
    is1 = socket1.getInputStream();


    bufferSize = socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
    bufferSize1 = socket1.getReceiveBufferSize();
    //bufferSize2 = socket2.getReceiveBufferSize();
    System.out.println("Buffer size: " + bufferSize);
    System.out.println("file recieved");
    System.out.println("Buffer size1: " + bufferSize1);
    System.out.println("file recieved");

    System.out.println("file recieved");
 } catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Can't get socket input stream. ");
 }


try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream("/home/reza/Desktop/reza");
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    fos1 = new FileOutputStream("/home/reza/Desktop/ali");
    bos1 = new BufferedOutputStream(fos1);




} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("File not found. ");
}

byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

int count;

while ((count = is.read(bytes)) > 0) {
   bos.write(bytes, 0, count);

}
byte[] bytes1 = new byte[bufferSize1];

int count1;
while ((count1 = is1.read(bytes1)) > 0) {
       bos1.write(bytes1, 0, count1);
    }


bos.flush();
bos.close();
bos1.flush();
bos1.close();
is.close();
is1.close();
socket.close();
serverSocket.close();
socket1.close();
serverSocket1.close();


 }

 public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException 
{
  System.out.println("server is run, please send file");



  Server s = new Server();
  s.recivefile();


}
}
```

client test class:

```
  import java.io.IOException;


 public class clientTest extends Thread {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{
   Client client = new Client();
   client.sendFile();
  }
  }
```

Comment: In order to help you better, I'd suggest you format your code so that its a bit easier to read

Comment: First, I would suggest that this is not a multi-threaded server. You have a single thread that is waiting for both connections before moving forward instead of two threads that could each receive data independantly. If this is HW you will probably lose a lot of points.

Comment: exactly,you are right, I've lost

Comment: Generally the way something like this works on the server is that there is a single thread that listens for new client connections. As soon as a connection is made this thread lauches another thread that manages that connection (reads, responds and closes the connection). Then the "new connection listener thread" immediately goes back to listening for new connections. As I state in my answer, the client can send an EOF marker that can let the server know when reading is complete and it can close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code in the server to be your issue:

```
while ((count = is.read(bytes)) > 0) {
   bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
}
byte[] bytes1 = new byte[bufferSize1];

int count1;
while ((count1 = is1.read(bytes1)) > 0) {
   bos1.write(bytes1, 0, count1);
}
bos.flush();
bos.close();
bos1.flush();
bos1.close();
is.close();
is1.close();
socket.close();
serverSocket.close();
socket1.close();
serverSocket1.close();
```

So the server has connected to the client, then it immediately checks to see if there are any bytes to read, if not it stops reading and closes the connection. If this happens faster than the client can deliver any bytes, boom, no data is received. And it WILL happend faster than the client can send data because the client is connecting THEN starting thread to send the data.

Instead, the server should read on each connection for as long as the client has maintained the connection alive. The server needs to wait for the data to be received.

Notice that in your code, the client is waiting for the server to close the connection. But how is the server supposed to know when all the data is sent? Either the client must close the connection or the client must send an EOF-type marker to the server indicating an end of the data and that it is safe to close the connection.